# e.forEach is not a function

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a simple scenario wherein I have to display data in the grid. I have worked with similar scenarios before but I'm not sure why this error is coming. 
The error in console says : e.forEach is not a function at at e.recursiveFunction (ag-grid-enterprise.min.js:2)

This doesn't point to a specific piece of code that I've written. I'm using ag-grid with angular 1.

Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to populate your ag-grid component with some data?

Comment: welcome to [so], would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]